# Javascript Popup Text Limit in IE8

Tags: javascript

Is there any limit to the amount of text that can be called via a Popup in javascript/jquery?

I have a popup that works fine in IE9, FF etc BUT does NOT work in IE8

The word count is 2667, is there any limitations in IE8 and can it be fixed via code?

Update: When I edit the text, the popup works. Still curios why IE8 would not load

Thanks

RG

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle or link to show what you mean? When you say it doesnt work, in what way? are you getting errors?

Comment: Probably need to see a code snippet. IE8 interprets things like trailing commas differently, so if your mechanism for populating the pop-up defines a class that has a trailing comma, that could cause the failure. I'd suggest running JSLint/JSHint against the source and then posting it here if you still have an issue.

Comment: Popup = alert()? A new window? a modal dialog? which type?